# Webpack 5: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'some/path/.svg'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-5

I'm in the process of upgrading Webpack 4 to 5. And I'm seeing an error specific to some .css files that use background: url('some/path'). These image paths are hosted on our server. The error goes away if I hardcode a complete path.

It can find the proper .css file, but looks like because url is used, its creating a module.

Webpack version: 5.75.0

Error:

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'some/server/path.svg'

CSS file snippet:

```
.accordion .toggle:after {
background: url('some/server/path.svg') no-repeat 100%;
```

}

Webpack Base Config:

```
        cssExtracter.push({
        mode: env,
        entry: {
            do_not_use: [
                mobileCssEntry
            ]
        },
        output: {
            publicPath: "",
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/assets'),
            filename: '[name].js'
        },
        plugins: [
            mCSS
        ],
        optimization: {
            minimizer: [new CssMinimizerPlugin({
                minimizerOptions: {
                    preset: [
                        "default",
                        {
                            discardComments: { removeAll: true },
                        },
                    ],
                },
            })],
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    exclude: [
                        /dist/
                    ],
                    use: ['babel-loader']
                },
                {
                    test: /\-m.css$/,
                    use: [{ loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
                        cssLoaderObj
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    })
```

I've tried a few solutions to add to the Rules block:

```
{
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
          },
        ],
       type: 'javascript/auto'
      },
```

And

```
                {
                    test: /\.svg/,
                    type: 'asset/inline'
                }
```